# How do I fix ESM and CommonJs import issues?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, es6-modules, commonjs

I'm currently working on an implementation of python contextmnagers in python and after writing the library using typescript, I decided it'll be cool to have builds for both ESM and commonJs. I made support for both types out of the box by doing this
[image: my package.json]

I didn't explicitly specify `type` in my main package.json, but I created separate package.json which contained the `type` for each build.

After doing all this, I discovered that my importing is now screwed up, my tests keep up throwing import errors, when I try to switch from one import method to another, a new error is born. Please how do I get out of this loop of madness?

[image: one of the many errors]

Comment: What is your file structure like? Is there a `with.ts` file in your `src` folder?

Comment: All the files are available